# Rails Translation error simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, translation

So I am working on application that will process background checks for licensing at one of the new casinos in Rhode Island. I built all my data input forms, built the database, and populated it with some dummy applicants. The next step was to create the actual function of the app and tie the tables together with a table I named cases.

So as part of the New Case page, I wanted to have a few drop down menus. Now this is my first time using this framework, but still I cannot believe I am getting this much difficulty with drop down menus. I googled how to make drop down menus with simple_form and this is what I got.

```
class Position
    KEYS = [
        CAGE_CASHIER = "Cage Cashier",
        DEALER = "Dealer",
        KEY_EMPLOYEE = "Key Employee",
        SECURTIY = "Security",
        SUPERVISOR = "Table Games Supervisor",
        ]   

    def self.keys 
        KEYS
    end

    def self.all
        keys.map{|key| new(key)}
    end

    def initialize(key)
        @key = key 
    end

    def id
        @key 
    end

    def name
        I18n.t(@key, scope: :"models.case.positions")
    end
end
```

My form page looks like

```
    <%= f.input :position, collection: Case::Position.all %>
```

Now, the drop down menu is generated and at first everything looks good, but when you click on the menu to see what your options are you get the following error:

```
     translation missing: en.models.case.positions.my_position
```

I googled that error message and everything I read over the last hour has just given me a headache to rival all other migraines in the history of the world. Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks
jpStearns

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  models:
    case:
      positions:
        my_position: "Whatever you want for your message"
```

If the value of name changes, you might be better off not using i18n since it requires you to add translations to a .yml file.

Comment: Where will "Whatever you want for your message" appear in the browser

Comment: It will appear in place of ''translation missing: en.models.case.positions.my_position". Because you're using i18n, you have to specify the translation in a YAML file

Comment: now it is saying 
        #<Case::Position:0x00000005853608>

Comment: See the note about i18n. Might not be the best route to go for what you're doing

Comment: scratch that the first option "dealer" was blank, but I put dealer in the "Dealer" as the message

Comment: I literally know no other way of making a drop down menu in simple form

Comment: No I wish now where it use to have that error message it is just blank

Comment: ahhh all this stuff about associations a config files I am losing my mind and pulling my hair out why cant it just be like <%= f.input :position as: :select :catagories[Dealer, Supervisor, Security] like there has to be an easier way to do this

Comment: SOLVED you were a really big help I just started coding a year ago how do I give you reputation?

Comment: You can accept the answer, and or upvote the answer. Glad it worked! Keep at it. Rails is an opinionated framework and just takes a bit of time to get used to.

Comment: How do i accept the answer I dont see that anywhere

Comment: Not entirely sure. I've never asked a question, but I know if it's your first one you have to wait a few minutes before you can accept.